# Extract .obb files in as3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, expansion

I have an app that I made using Flash CS6 and Adobe AIR which exceeds the Google Play Limit of 50Mb. So I am using expansion files which is an .obb file inside which are several swf's which I need to extract using as3. The expansion files get downloaded to the /Android/obb/my_package_name/ folder and I am able to find it in my code below, but I got stuck while extracting the files from the obb file. **Using FZIP Class did not help (It extracts .zip files but not .obb).** Following is my code

```
file = File.userDirectory.resolvePath(path + "/" + filename);
if (file.exists)
{
    loadSwf();
}

function loadSwf():void 
{
    fileStream = new FileStream(); 
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
    bytes = new ByteArray();
    fileStream.readBytes(bytes);
    trace(bytes);
    fileStream.close(); 

    var cont:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
    cont.allowCodeImport = true;

    applicationLoader = new Loader();
    applicationLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleAppLoaded);
    applicationLoader.loadBytes(bytes, cont);
}

function handleAppLoaded(e:Event):void 
{
    addChild(applicationLoader);
    /* Now how to extract the swf's from within the obb */
}
```

Comment: What kind of file format is `*.obb`? I think there should be ways to export SWFs from such an obb, if this is a supported extension, but I don't know any.

Comment: The OBB file extension is associated with the Google Android operating system for smart phones and tablets.

Answer (score 0):

.obb are zip files, rename it then use fzip to read its contents. Be aware as Google Play itself say that on some device .obb files might fail to be installed with your app. In that case they offer hosting of your .obb file for free but if you don't want your users to wait for the .obb download you'll have to switch to a different system.

I personally skip that step and download directly to device the missing files (only sounds or in some cases graphics) and save them on disc.